# How do I save a TensorFlow mulit-task recommendation model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recommendation-engine

So I followed this tutorial and the model trains just fine (https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/multitask?hl=en).
My question is how do i save the trained model so that it can be used for serving? The individual ranking and retrieval model are saved in very different ways:

- To save the retrieval model you encapsulate it into a BruteForce Layer and create an index that contains the possible candidates https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval#making_predictions
- To save the ranking model you simply call tf.saved_model.save( ) https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_ranking#exporting_for_serving

So how do I combine these two steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the second method of ClaudiaR answer here:
[How to save tensorflow recommenders framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73659720/how-to-save-tensorflow-recommenders-framework-model)

```
model.save_weights('content_model_weights', save_format='tf')
loaded_model = MultiTaskModel(user_model, movie_model, task)
loaded_model.load_weights('content_model_weights')
```

The issue for me is that you still need to call your `MultiTaskModel` class, which leads to the need of loading the `unique_movie_titles`, `unique_user_id` and other unique lists which you have put in the model.